# How to shutdown Derby in-memory database Properly

Tags: java, derby, shutdown, in-memory-database

I'm using derby as an embedded database. Furthermore, I'm using it's in-memory database option for my unit tests.

What I can't figure out is how to properly shut down [(A quick look at the code)](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html) the Derby database. I beleive I have it working for a standard database but I'm getting different exceptions when attempt similar code on a in-memory database.

I'm going to omit details, I'll add them if other feel are needed.

Basically, I'm trying to shut down my database in these two fashions where my in-memory database is consistently called "eh":

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:memory:eh;shutdown=true");
```

then:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:eh;shutdown=true");
```

The former results in [an exception but not the one expected](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.5/devguide/tdevdvlp20349.html). The details are:

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database 'memory:eh' shutdown.

The latter results in

> java.sql.SQLException: Database 'eh' not found.

Based on what I've been able to figure out, we want a `SQLException` but not the one we receive. On the other hand, the `SQLNonTransientConnectionException` error seems more appropriate but isn't the right type (though it is derived from `SQLException`) nor does it have the right state code. The state code end up being: `08006`.

The example code I have illustrates that a `SQLException` with a SQL state of "XJ015".

Note: The example I'm referencing is: [WwdEmbedded Program](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/getstart/rwwdactivity3.html) ([Java Code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/db/derby/code/trunk/java/demo/workingwithderby/WwdEmbedded.java)).

Comment: Using drop instead of shutdown seems what you want. shutdown seems to not drop the database.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

XJ015 (with `SQLCODE` 50000) is the expected (successful) `SQLSTATE` for complete system shutdown.  08006 (with `SQLCODE` 45000), on the other hand, is the expected `SQLSTATE` for shutdown of only an individual database.

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");
```

Shuts down the entire system and should result in `XJ015`.

Answer (score 14):

The URL "jdbc:derby:memory:eh;shutdown=true" results in the expected 08006 error code, but doesn't actually remove the DB from memory.  If later on, you try to create a new database with "jdbc:derby:memory:eh;create=true", you'll get an error saying that the database already exists.

Fortunately, as of Derby 10.6.1.0 (released on May 17, 2010), it is possible to actually drop an in-memory database using a URL of the form "jdbc:derby:memory:eh;drop=true".  See the [release notes](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/db/derby/code/tags/10.6.1.0/RELEASE-NOTES.html?view=co#New%20Features) and the page [Using in-memory databases](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/devguide/cdevdvlpinmemdb.html).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your first code example is fine. The SQL State difference that you are seeing, I believe, is because you are running Derby embedded, but the example code that you saw (with SQL state XJ015) was running in a client-server configuration.

As you noted, the SQLNonTransientConnectionException is a subclass of SQLException, so I am confused as to why you think you are not getting the right type of exception.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I eventually came to the same conclusion as you but still have no evidence it's right, aside from you agreement. I even tried searching the Derby Source. The example I'm referencing is the WwdEmbedded.java which is a Embedded example. Also, the Documentation indicates to expect a SQLException... Not SQLException or a descendant. That said, I do accept this as a possible idea which is why I mentioned the relationship in the first place.